# Get data from firestore by using user uid

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem.
I need to get data from firestore, and want to assign collection to my variable, but the function doesn't wait to finish firebase.auth,and run console.log at the bottom. Maybe I have a problem with async.
What should I do to return my collection?
I use the function:

```
async function getDaySpending(period="7-2020"){
  let arrayOfSpending=[];
 await firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( function(user) {
    if (user) {
    firebaseApp.firestore().collection(user.uid).doc(period).get().then(doc=>{
        if(doc.exists){
          
     arrayOfSpending=doc.data().spending;       //assign value
     console.log(arrayOfSpending)     //return proper collection,run second
        }})
    } 
  }); 
console.log(arrayOfSpending);  //return null,run first
return arrayOfSpending
}
```

**EDIT**
I don't want to start a new topic, because it is related.
My code:

```
init()

async function init () {
     await userIsActive()
    console.log("in init");     
  await getDaySpending();
    console.log("after") */
    
}

function userIsActive(){
    firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user=>{
    if(user){
      console.log("user is active");
      return true
    }else{
      console.log("no user");
      return false
    }
  })
  }

 function getDaySpending(period = '7-2020') {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if(!user) return;      //I got null instead user data
    const uid = user.uid;
    const snap  = await  firebase.firestore().collection(uid).doc(period).get();
    if(snap.exists) {
      return snap.data().spending;
    } else {
      // handle the case where there was no data
    }
  }
```

I got a response in the console like:
"in init","after","null","user is active"
but I want to receive a response like :
"user is active", "in init", user data instead null,"after";

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

`then` and `await` do the same thing. You don't want to mix them up, and generally speaking, `await` is the newer more cleaner way of handling async functions, so you should pretty much always use `await` whenever possible.

You can rewrite the code to something like this, but I was not sure what you want to return at the end:

```
async function getDaySpending(period = '7-2020') {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if(!user) return; // if user is not signed in, return or do whatever you want to here
    const uid = user.uid;
    const snap  = await  firebase.firestore().collection(uid).doc(period).get();
    if(snap.exists) {
      return snap.data().spending;
    } else {
      // handle the case where there was no data
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried in this way, but the function firebase.auth().currentUser--> return null. I need to use onAuthStateChanged --> return user.

Comment: @Sebastian You just have to make sure `getDaySpending` gets called after you know that firebase auth is loaded. Where and how are you calling `getDaySpending`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't check it. I need to fix it